# Jquery Event on a Ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

How can I run jquery function for a `.click()` event on a element created by an ajax request ?

For a normal element it works, but I want to do this for an element created by the ajax request. And it's not working ...

```
$(".links").click(function(){alert("aaaa");})

a class="links" >1</a;
```

I've also tried with "links" as id.
I need it for a pagination system.

Please help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run the code again to bind the click event handler, after the new element is inserted into the DOM. Alternatively, you may want to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: I mean executing `$(".links").click(...)` after you append the new hyperlinks (however you do it, through `load()`, or `append()`, or whatever).

Comment: You are a genius.I've made it with .live. It works!!! You've ended two hours of desperate searching! Thank you so much

Comment: and for a onclick added to the <a>? How should I do?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know if the onclick in your newly added HTML code will run or not. In any case, it is usually a bad idea to mix jQuery bound events with native events.

Answer (score 1):

use [jquery live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1):

use jquery live,

```
$(".links").live('click', function(){
    //user code here
});
```

to deal with dynamically loaded doms, you should use live function.
jquery do not load page doms automatically after page loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You should use live() like this:

```
$(".links").live('click', function(){alert("aaaa");})
```

This also works with elements added to document

for an onclick to every `<a>` element you must do like this (if this is what you mean:

```
$("a").live('click', function(){
      alert($(this).attr("id"));
    })
```

This attaches event to all `<a>` elements and also to those added afterwards.

EDIT - now the alert shows the id of the link: 'this' in this case refers to the `<a>` that has been clicked

Comment: and for a onclick added to the <a>? How should I do?

Comment: May I get the id of that "a" somehow?